# Is it possible to apply a transformation with OpenCV on Python but only on the margin of an image?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to apply an OpenCV transformation using python but only on the border/margin of an image.

In particular I'm trying to apply the

```
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

from [this link](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) on the image below in order to denoise the border of my Post-it note.

Many thanks for your help!

[image: Image Example]

Comment: I don't know what you want to do but you always can get part of image `part = img[ row_start:row_end , col_start:col_end ]`. And later you can replace it in similar way `img[ row_start:row_end , col_start:col_end ] = part`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @furas ! Yes I thought of doing that, but I thought it would be difficult to generalise it as i have to do a similar transformation on multiple images like the one above.

Comment: if you don't know how to generalize it then if exists code for this then it may have also problem to generalize it.

Comment: Do you know the margin coordinates in the frame.?